# Laravel 8. Can I to get an array of stores revenue by date for one request?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, php-7.3

I need to get an array of stores revenue values (their arbitrary number, say 100) for arbitrary dates, as in the picture.

[image]

All sales are recorded in one "stores" table.
I can retrieve the value for each cell with a query:

```
$result = DB::connection('pgsql')->table('markets')
    ->whereDate('date', '=', $date)
    ->where('market', '=', $market)
    ->sum('price');
```

I can do a foreach by date, inside a foreach by shopping, and in 3000 queries form a table.
However, it seems to me that this result can be obtained with one request. Can anyone suggest a solution, or give an example of similar queries? I don't understand where to start constructing a query.

*Laravel 8, PostgreSQL, PHP 7.3*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupBy()`:

```
$result = DB::connection('pgsql')->table('markets')
    ->groupBy([ 'date', 'market' ])
    ->sum('price');
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about groupBy. I managed to reduce the number of requests from ~3000 to 28-31 (depending on the number of days in the month), which is already quite good.

`for ($i = $date1; $i <= $date2; $i->modify('+1 day')) {$budgets[$i->format("Y-m-d")] = DB::connection('pgsql')->table('markets')->whereDate('date', '=', $i->format("Y-m-d"))->groupBy('market')->selectRaw('sum(price) as sum, market')->pluck('sum', 'market');
}`